# How Do I Write into an array on a seperate file?

Tags: python, arrays, file

I am trying to save the date into an array (log[]) in a separate file("file.txt").
How would I do this?

I've opened the file itself but I don't know how to open log[] in that file and append data to it.

```
x = input("Please Enter Name: ")
  y = input("Please Enter Phone Number: ")
  z = input("Please Enter Room Number: ")
  with open("log.txt", "a") as f:
    with open("log[]", "a") as g:
      g.write("Name: " + x)
      g.write("Phone Number: " + y)
      g.write("Room Number: " + z)

when doing this, it opened up a new file called log[] and saved it into there, not the actual array in log.txt. Then log.txt displayed that the login crashed
```

Comment: Can you tell what do you expect to be written in the file?

Comment: I am trying to save three value into the array on the file and be able to recall them afterwards

Comment: Would help to write or tag language.

Comment: You are not reading anything from `log.txt`. you are just appending the values read from input to `log[]`

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem with this python script.

```
x = input("Please Enter Name: ")
y = input("Please Enter Phone Number: ")
z = input("Please Enter Room Number: ")

# {} are the place holder of x, y and z
# \n means new line at the end of each write done in the file.
log = '[{}, {}, {}]\n'.format(x, y, z)

# footxt in the same dir as the python script.
file_handler = open('footxt.txt', 'a')
file_handler.writelines(log)
file_handler.close()
```

The output of the script, when the script is run 2 times will look like this, in the `foo.txt` file.

> [name, 888888, 01]
>
> [name2, 998878, 02]

Code to print the foo.txt file to screen.

```
file_handler = open('footxt.txt')

for line in file_handler.readlines():
    print (line)

file_handle.close()
```

Comment: Thanks - how would I retrieve these from the file and print them on the originia program?